# Can I create a web component from a vue component that uses other vue components in it?

Tags: vuejs3, web-component, micro-frontend

I have the following use case.
I have a project made in vue3 which is really a microfrontend, so it represents a smaller part of a whole application made with this framework.

In my microfront, there are 3 components that I want other microfrontends to be able to use. Since we are in the process of migrating things from vue2 to vue3, we want these components to be able to work with all of the microfronts that need them, whether they are in vue2 or vue3.

For this, we thought that turning our 'exportable' components to web components would be an interesting idea to explore. The issue is that these components are using other vue3 components from the project which we don't plan to convert to web components.

So my question is, is the web component's approach a possible solution taking this information into consideration? I want to point out that we also use the project's vuex store for some actions that take place within the component's we want to convert.

Comment: SO is about helping you code, so you post code and we fix it. So try this yourself, you can test this in 1 hour